# How can I center an image with text that follows it using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<p style="line-height: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;"> </p>
<div class="icon sprite-book-open" style="margin-right: 5px"></div>
Topic: No Topic Title
<p></p>
```

and my CSS is like this:

```
.icon {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url(/Images/fugue/sprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
.sprite-book-open{ background-position: 0 -288px;  }
```

Is there some way that I could do this **without** paragraphs and so the picture icon lines up with the text. Right now the icon 
looks a few pixels too high. I guess I need some way to center this in 
the line but I am not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
    .icon {
        line-height: 1.6em;
        padding: 0 0 0 40px;
        background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32x32_0120/book_open.png') no-repeat 5px 50%
    }

</style>
<div class="icon sprite-book-open">
    <p>
        Topic: No Topic Title
    </p>
</div>
```

---

```
<style>
    .icon {
    display:inline-block;
    height:32px;
    width:32px;
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/32x32_0120/book_open.png') no-repeat center center }
    span {

    }
    p, span, .icon {vertical-align:middle}

</style>

<p>
    <div class="icon sprite-book-open"></div>
    <span>Topic: No Topic Title</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a vertical alignment of `bottom` for the icon:

```
vertical-align:bottom;
```

If you want to get rid of all the unnecessary markup, consider:

HTML:

```
<div class="title sprite-book-open" style="margin-right: 5px">
Topic: No Topic Title
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.title{
    line-height: 16px;
}
.title:before {
    background-color: transparent;
    content: " ";
    background-image: url(/Images/fugue/sprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.sprite-book-open:before{ 
    background-position: 0 -288px;  
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/V4EM6/8/

Comment: But can I do this using just one DIV instead of paragraphs? If so then where would I put your CSS ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't change the .icon css directly. It's used all over our project. All I can do is an inline style.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="icon sprite-book-open" style="margin-right: 5px"></div>
    <div class="text">Topic: No Topic Title</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.text{float:left;margin-top:5px;}
.icon{float:left;margin-top:5px}
```

You can now adjust margin-top to get them aligned. You can use margin-left to create space between icon and text.

Comment: Is there a way I could use the vertical align instead of adjusting things with margins to line up? Thanks?

Comment: vertical-align has almost never worked for me (for non text items). Another option is to use tables (bit retro but does great vertical align)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood what you are trying to do, but if you want to put an icon in front of a paragraph, the best way is to use padding left and background.

```
<style>
.paragraph-with-icon {
    background:url(http://www.pangoo.it/img/pangoo.gif) no-repeat;
    padding:0 0 0 120px;
    line-height: 53px;
}
</style>


<p class="paragraph-with-icon">
Topic: No Topic Title
</p>
```

I used an icon of 100x53 px in the example (120px is 100px + 20 of spacing).

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/apFvw/1/

If you want it aligned to top of image, change:

```
line-height: 53px;
```

with

```
height: 53px;
```

or

```
min-height: 53px;
```

(and there are solutions for browsers not supporting min-height)

You can use margins on the same paragraph to adjust spacing without adding divs and extra markup.